# How to allow argument in two different formats in a lua function?

Tags: string, function, lua, arguments, lua-table

I have a function which accepts table (multi-dimensional arrays) as arguments. I want to change it to accept argument in multiple formats.

Here is the function.

```
matrix.deter({{3,4,5},{2,4,6},{7,8,10}})
```

This works fine. But I want to change it even to accept the argument as

```
matrix.deter({(3,4,5),(2,4,6),(7,8,10)})
```

So both of the following will give same output.

```
matrix.deter({{3,4,5},{2,4,6},{7,8,10}})

matrix.deter({(3,4,5),(2,4,6),(7,8,10)})
```

In other words, inner arrays are in round parentheses instead of curly braces. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What is `(3,4,5)`? It's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function.

```
local function m(...) return {...} end

matrix.deter(m(3,4,5), m(2,4,6), m(7,8,10))
```

Or a string

```
matrix.deter({"(3,4,5)", "(2,4,6)", "(7,8,10)"})
```

Both doesn't make to much sense if you're working with a list of numbers.

You cannot change Lua's tokens, just because you don't like their look.
You'll have to find another way.